# Minimize memory allocations while calculating the matrix representation of a Hamiltonian

Tags: performance, matrix, memory-optimization, julia

I am writing a script using Julia (calling my functions from the REPL) to compute the matrix representation of certain Hamiltonian. After I run my script I see that the memory allocations count is considerably high:

```
julia> @time hamiltonian(40, 20);
      5.860412 seconds (76.33 M allocations: 2.085 GiB, 23.78% gc time)
```

The time it takes to execute has not been an issue, but I would like to know **how could I write this script as a more idiomatic (but still optimal) Julia code while trying to minimize the memory allocations?**

This is my script until now:

```
const ω = ω0 = 1
const γ = 1

myFactorial(x) = factorial(big(x))
G(j) = (2 * γ) / (ω * sqrt(2*j))
    
function cMinus(j::Int, m::Real)
    sqrt(j * (j + 1) - m * (m - 1))
end
    
function cPlus(j::Int, m::Real)
    sqrt(j * (j + 1) - m * (m + 1))
end


# Function to compute the overlap in the BCE base.
function overlap(
    n_bra::Int,
    m_bra::Real,
    n_ket::Int,
    m_ket::Real,
    j::Int
    )
    newG(m_bra, m_ket) = G(j) * (m_bra - m_ket)
    sum_num(n_bra, n_ket, k) = (-1)^(n_ket - k) * 
        sqrt(bigFactorial(n_bra) * bigFactorial(n_ket)) * 
        newG(m_bra, m_ket)^(n_bra + n_ket -2*k)
    sum_den(n_bra, n_ket, k) = bigFactorial(k) * 
        bigFactorial(n_bra - k) * 
        bigFactorial(n_ket - k)
    if m_bra == m_ket && n_bra != n_ket
        return 0
    else
        term1 = exp(- newG(m_bra, m_ket)^2 / 2)
        # term2 = [sum_num(n_bra, n_ket, k) / sum_den(n_bra, n_ket, k) 
        #   for k=0:min(n_bra, n_ket)]
        term2 = sum(sum_num(n_bra, n_ket, k) / 
            sum_den(n_bra, n_ket, k) 
            for k=0:min(n_bra, n_ket))
        return term1 * sum(term2)
    end
end


# Matrix representation of the Hamiltonian for the specified `n_max` and `j`.
function hamiltonian(n_max::Int, j::Int)
    n_range = 0:n_max
    m_range = -j:j
    dim = (2*j + 1) * (n_max + 1)
    temp = zeros(dim, dim)
    col = 1
    for n_ket = n_range, m_ket = m_range
        row = 1
        for n_bra = n_range, m_bra = m_range
            if row >= col
                # Me encuentro en el estado (n_bra, m_bra, n_ket, m_ket)
                if n_bra == n_ket && m_bra == m_ket
                    temp[row, col] = ω * (n_ket - (G(j) * m_ket)^2)
                elseif m_bra == m_ket + 1
                    temp[row, col] = temp[col, row] = (- ω0 / 2) * 
                        cPlus(j, m_ket) * 
                        overlap(n_bra, m_bra, n_ket, m_ket, j)
                elseif m_bra == m_ket - 1
                    temp[row, col] = temp[col, row] = (- ω0 / 2) * 
                        cMinus(j, m_ket) * 
                        overlap(n_bra, m_bra, n_ket, m_ket, j)
                end
            end
            row += 1
        end
        col += 1
    end
    temp
end
```

One minimal example of my script working is the following:

```
julia> @time hamiltonian(1, 1)
  0.000064 seconds (881 allocations: 27.984 KiB)
6×6 Matrix{Float64}:
 -2.0       -0.26013    0.0        0.0       -0.367879   0.0
 -0.26013    0.0       -0.26013    0.367879   0.0       -0.367879
  0.0       -0.26013   -2.0        0.0        0.367879   0.0
  0.0        0.367879   0.0       -1.0        0.26013    0.0
 -0.367879   0.0        0.367879   0.26013    1.0        0.26013
  0.0       -0.367879   0.0        0.0        0.26013   -1.0
```

I was able to reduce the memory allocations by considering the symmetry of the problem. The approach I took was to compute the values for the main diagonal and those located in the lower-half of the matrix. Then those values are "transposed" to fill the upper-half as `M[i,j] = M[j,i]`. An example of the time and allocations reduction is shown below:

```
julia> @time hamiltonian(40, 20)
  2.917963 seconds (39.69 M allocations: 1.129 GiB, 25.57% gc time)
```

Although, I would like to call `hamiltonian(n_max, j)` with much higher values of `n_max` and `j`, around `n_max=300` and `j=200`.

---

### Some mathematical background

For sake of completeness the mathematical expression of the Hamiltonian is:

$$
\begin{align}
\langle N', m'_{x} | \hat{H} | N, m_{x} \rangle = & \omega \left[N - (G m_{x})^{2}\right] \delta_{N' N} \delta_{m'_{x} m_{x}} \\
& - \frac{\omega_{0}}{2} \left[C_{+}(j,m_{x}) \delta_{m'_{x} (m_{x}+1)} + C_{-}(j,m_{x}) \delta_{m'_{x} (m_{x}-1)}\right] {}_{m_{x}}\langle N' | N \rangle_{m_{x}}
\end{align}
$$

The last term in \$\langle\hat{H}\rangle\$ is the overlap between states, it is given by:

$$
\begin{align}
{}_{m'_{x}}\langle N' | N \rangle_{m_{x}} = & \exp\left[-\frac{G^{2}}{2} (m'_{x} - m_{x})^2\right] \\
& \sum_{k=0}^{min\{N',N\}} \frac{(-1)^{N-k} \sqrt{N! N'!}}{k! (N-k)! (N'-k)!} \left[G(m'_{x} - m_{x})\right]^{N+N'-2k}
\end{align}
$$

Additionally, the \$C\$ coefficients are obtained as:

$$
C_{\pm}(j,m) = \sqrt{j(j + 1) - m(m \pm 1)} $$

The following constants are used in this specific case:

$$
\omega = \omega_{0} = \gamma = 1 $$

And the constant \$G\$ is:

$$
G = \frac{2 \gamma}{\omega \sqrt{2 j}}$$

Comment: Could you add a picture of or link to the original math formula? Might be relevant to ensure correctness of refactorings.

Comment: Of course, I added the  brief mathematical background of the problem with the formulas that are needed for this matrix. It is a formula that a colleague derived, though.

Comment: The math equations block is a known bug, reported [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10778/52915) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342761/269301).

Comment: @Mast , thank you. I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is you want `const ω = const ω0 = 1`. The second problem is harder, but basically you are computing way too many factorials rather than computing `sum_num(n_bra, n_ket, k) / sum_den(n_bra, n_ket, k)`, for each `k` you should look for the formula that computes the `k+1`th term from the `k`th term. This will only use multiplication/division, so you won't need to use factorials. If you don't need factorials, you won't get overflow, so you won't need `BigFloat`s and your allocations will vanish, and your code will be about 100x faster.

Comment: I did defined those variables in the first place but they are only equal in this specific scenario, I can change it to stop assigning the value twice but does it really represents a memory penalty?  I will look into your suggestion to obtain an expression for the k+1 term, I blindly wrote the expressions in Julia without considering this.